# Micorsoft Graph Rest Api itemNotFound Problem

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I'm using Http rest api call in powerautomate to send an invitation one time passcode for site:

```
GET
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/dfdee735-2ec7-43fa-b151-0934c27c3f03/drive/items/01NGPTUI6UIBPAHEBK7NGZGZDCSPISWLI4
```

and i have error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "The resource could not be found."
  }
}
```

I know the file exists because previosly I use endpoint:

```
Get
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/dfdee735-2ec7-43fa-b151-0934c27c3f03/lists/99b45b02-20b8-4530-b434-ec45316fab3e/items/1/driveItem
```

that return me "id": "01NGPTUI6UIBPAHEBK7NGZGZDCSPISWLI4"
siteId is also correct, because i tried with

```
"id": "01NGPTUI6UIBPAHEBK7NGZGZDCSPISWLI4" 
"parentReference": {
    "id": "01NGPTUI56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ",
    "siteId": "dfdee735-2ec7-43fa-b151-0934c27c3f03"
}
```

and for it, its works, but its different folder, and wants to specifically use the id of the site Home.aspx file, which is under Id 01NGPTUI6UIBPAHEBK7NGZGZDCSPISWLI4, but it returns the above error "The resource could not be found."

I tried with the other files I received in parentReference, but unfortunately it does not provide the file I want